# Draw monthly data in geofacet US maps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data `df` with the format

| State | Date | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AL | 2019-01 | 10.1 |
| AL | 2019-02 | 12.1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| NY | 2019-01 | 15.1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And I would like to draw a time series with the geofacet package. I am having troubles with the Date format I guess.

`ggplot(df,aes(Date, Ratio)) + geom_line() + facet_geo(~ State, grid = "us_state_grid2") + ylab("Rate (%)")`

The following errors shown:*geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you
need to adjust the group aesthetic?*

How I can adjust it?

Comment: Is your date variable class Date or is it a character? Characters are handled differently than Date objects. If it's a character vector, you might need to group by state.

Comment: Often `geom_line` requires you to set `group` in `aes` to tell it which points should be connected. Scroll down to see the line graph examples [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html). If you put your data in more usable format using `dput(df)` we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date is structured 'yyyy-mm', so I'm guessing it's a character vector rather than a date object. You should convert it to class Date with `as.Date()` and then it should work as expected. (You'll need to `paste` on the day of the month.)

You get a grouping error because when your x-axis is a character vector, `geom_line` will *group by values of the character vector x-axis*. Lines are drawn instead between the various `y` values at each `x` value. Here's an example using the `geofacet` package's own `state_ranks` dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(geofacet)

data(state_ranks)


# The lines are not connected across a character x-axis.
ggplot(state_ranks) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = variable, y = rank))

# Throws error: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do 
#               you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
ggplot(state_ranks) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = variable, y = rank)) + 
  facet_geo(~ state)
```

If you group by state, you get the expected result (with an alphabetically ordered x-axis).

```r
# Works, x-axis is alphabetized and lines are connected
ggplot(state_ranks) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = variable, y = rank, group = state)) + 
  facet_geo(~ state)
```

Comment: It works even `class(df$Date)` is "character". I wrote the following ```ggplot(df) +
geom_line(aes(Date, Ratio,group=state)) +
facet_geo(~ state, grid = "us_state_grid2")```. The main problem was I did not group by state in `aes()` in `geom_line`

Comment: Yes, that was the last part of my answer. Be careful, because the x-axis will be ordered alphabetically. Depending on the format of the date, this can be out of order. (In your case it's fine.)

Comment: I will follow the `as.Date()` advice next time since this time the data is ascending in time order.